# How to covert string value to datetime

Tags: r, csv, datetime

I have a csv file where the date is stored in mm/dd/yyyy format 8/18/2015  12:23:57 PM. When I import this file, it gets imported in string format.

How to convert this to datetime value after importing? I tried to convert while importing, but all the values were as NA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `POSIXct`

```
as.POSIXct(str1, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "8/18/2015 12:23:57 PM"
```

Comment: I am new to R. I am using following code to import csv file. dt <- read.csv("emp.csv") -- col name is stdate , which i want to convert                                         dt will become dataframe. how to use ur commands to convert all the column value. Thanks in advance

Comment: @maankumar Try `dt$myCleanDate <- as.POSIXct(dt$stdate, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")`. Also, invest some time learning [basics of R](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info).

Comment: After doing this all the values became N/A. Any idea what went wrong.

Comment: @Kumar The code is based on the format you showed and zx8754's code should work if your format is the same

Comment: Thanks it worked.